# Get img size with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I try to get the width and height of more `img` on one page with jQuery or Javascript and I tried a lot of options such as:

```
height = this.naturalHeight
```

and

```
height = this.height
```

and

```
height = this.actualHeight
```

But nothing works. I always get a height of 0.

So the question is: **why** does it not work and **how** does it work well?

Here's the code: **(EDITED TO THE BEST ANSWER)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img.albums').load(function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
    if(width > height){
      $(this).addClass('landscape');
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you add more code? Show the relevant HTML as well as some more context for your javascript.

Comment: Can you show your code? Are you sure `this` is the image?

Comment: I edited the code from this fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vZNj7/1/)

Comment: Please EDIT the OP to **include the relevant HTML** code.  Dumping a link is not an acceptable substitute.

Comment: Use $(this) instead of this in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're querying the image before its in the page you usually end up getting 0.

As a test, once your page has loaded (and the image within it), open the console, grab your element using querySelector (or $ or whatever) and then grab the dimensions. See what you get.

Comment: Now I get the correct answer! How can I update the code to make it work?

Comment: You'll have to wait til the images have loaded. Each image tag will fire a load event when its ready. I suspect jQuery will wrap this for you, try replacing {each} with {load} in your example snippet. With a bit of luck the load event will then fire the event for all images returned by your query. I think jQuery will even scope it for you so that {{this}} is what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: I would +1 if I could! ;)

Answer (score 0):

give the image an ID
then

```
$("imageID").height();
$("imageID").width();
```

or simply integrate this

this

```
$(this).height();
    $(this).width();
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `this`, if that is possible in case

Comment: It could be an option. But he needs to get the size of a specific image.

Comment: oh yes. now it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to get original dimension of image:

```
var image = $("img")[0]; 
 $("<img/>").attr("src", $(img).attr("src")).load(function() {
    var pic_real_width = this.width;   
    var pic_real_height = this.height;
});
```

$(this).width() will not  work for in memory images.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img.albums').each(function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
    if(width > height){
      console.log("Width:", width, "height:", height)
      $(this).addClass('landscape');
      console.log("Hoi")
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jquery then you should first reference image:

HTML code:

```
<h2>Spectacular Mountains</h2>
<img id='myImage' class='dummyClass' src="pic_mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px">
```

JS via ids

```
$('#myImage').width()
$('#myImage').height()
```

JS via class selector

```
$('.dummyClass').width()
$('.dummyClass').height()
```